# Excel VBA to sum up a based on almost the same description

Tags: vba, excel, find

**My issue:**

I have some data, whereas the base of the value is the same, but in the end, it could be somethign else, like:

V573589
V574695
V574695A
V574695B

**Goal:**

I want a macro to identify, when it finds either "A" or "B" in the end of the cell, and delete the "A" and "B" in the end. On top of that, I want it to either delete the first rows with the value same description, or it could sum the 3 values.

At the moment I have tried with .Find("B",Lookat:=xlPart)... But without any luck :(

Answer (score 0):

To find values with the letter on the end:

```
Dim rng as Range
dim cl as Range

set rng = /define your column with data here/
for each cl in rng
If Right(cl, 1) = "A" Or Right(cl, 1) ="B" Then
    'Do whatever you want to
End If
```

In place of the comment inside the loop you could delete the last character:

```
cl = Left(cl, Len(cl)-1))
```

and then, in the next step, sum or delete, as you wish.

Comment: With the last statement you gave me, `cl = Left(cl, Len(cl)-1)` this codeline, will delete the last character, I assume? Just a quick bonus question, I would like to know, if so I can search for if the last characters in a cell is a letter, then delete all of the letters on the end, even if there’s more than one :)

Comment: To check if the character is a letter, you may use AscW function. It returns between 65 and 122 if the argument is a letter of standard Latin charset.

Comment: @PatrickS: If you have several letters at the end, you will need a loop through the string in the cell and use the AscW function, to check if the current letter is a letter or number. In this case, you might want to consider the `MID`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions as well as `LEN` (which is already shown in MarcinSzaleniec answer). You need to adjust the if statement as well.

Comment: @Prextor Ah, okay... Then it sounds like the answer of MarcinSzaleniec is the "easiest" way after all :)